# With aws-cdk-lib, how to get the value of a token?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-cdk

I instantiate my Cognito Pool as follow :

```
const cognitoUserPool = new cognito.UserPool(this, `Blablabla`, {
```

Later in my code from another stack, I'm trying to get the userPoolId ( to generate the issuerUrl ) with `cognitoUserPool.userPoolId` but its value is `${Token[TOKEN.317]}`, so I cannot generate the URL.

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Don't abandon your questions, please.

Answer (score 0):

The value of any token will be resolved during deployment. So you can still generate your URLs and pass it as a prop to other constructs or as environment variables to your containers/lambdas/etc - the token in the string will be substituted with the actual value during deployment.

Comment: ok my bad, the `userPoolId` already includes the AWS region, I just needed to remove it.

Comment: Can you clarify the comment? I don't understand what you're referring to. You need to remove a string from a token?